# Renaming the TriabgleIndices Property and Error Message

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-express

I am using C# Express Edition - 2008 developing tool. I intend to form a 3D mesh object by using an array of 100.000 items. To be able to form the 3D mesh, I must use thousands of "mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(...);" . But this is not a good application due to unnecessary code amount. I have to use the shortened coding, such as "mesh.Tai.Add(...);".

After executing Refactoring>Rename, system gives the following error message:
"**Rename failed. The definition is not in C# project in the current solution**"

How to solve this problem ?
Please, help ! :-)

Kind Regards
Oner YILMAZ

Comment: Just noticed that this question is a continuation of another:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813285/how-to-rename-the-triangleindices-property

Answer (score 0):

`TriangleIndices` is the name of a property of the `MeshGeometry3D` class that is in a referenced assembly.  You cannot rename it.

If you must create the mesh with code (better would be to use a modeling tool to create the mesh as a file) consider using a helper method to shorten things:

```
private void AddTI(MeshGeometry3D mesh, int index)
{
    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(index);
}
```

Seriously consider why you're doing this, though.  Modeling tools make easy work of creating meshes in standard formats, and you only need a couple of lines of code to load a mesh file.